# No class def error for a class deployed in websphere 6.0

Tags: java, websphere, noclassdeffounderror

In Websphere 6.0, I have a web application deployed "Project1". I am getting following error:-
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.app.X
    at java.lang.Class.initialize(Class.java:318)
    at com.app.Y.invoke(Y.java:61)

where both com.app.X and com.app.Y are part of separate jar files present in \WEB-INF\lib directory.
FYI, classloading policy is ParentFirst/application.

I have tried deployment multiple times and restart. Any clue what else I can try?

---

thanks Manglu and Bkail for your inputs. But issue was jar containing Y class was compiled on java1.4 version along with jar containing X class. However due to wrong checkin our CVS system, somebody compiled jar containing X class  with different version of java. So during runtime, when Y class's classloader tried to locate the particular class version of X, it could not find it. Based on my understanding, there are 4 reasons why we can get noClassDefFound error in J2EE/JAVA environment:-
i) Class is actual missing in classpath
ii) Class is present but not visible in classloader hierarchy
iii) Class is present but it is of different version.
iv) As explained above, Class is present but having trouble in class initialization process.

Anything else do you want to add?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that com.app.X failed in its `<clinit>` method, which causes the JVM to mark it as bad, and all subsequence attepmts to reference the class will result in NoClassDefFoundError.  The 1.5 JVMs include a `(initialization failure)` tag in the exception message, but WAS 6.0 uses 1.4.2 JVMs.  Look through the logs for `com.app.X.<clinit>` to find the real cause of the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Try and provide the stack trace for the folks here to help you.

As bkail mentioned, it does look like com.app.X fails during its intialization as a result of which you receive a NCDF error.

Deploying it multiple times will not help unless you see why the X fail during its initialization. Check if it has any static initialization blocks.

Both X and Y may exist and for X to be loaded by the classloader if X depends on an ABC which is not present, it could result in NCDF for X.

HTH
Manglu